# Not able to change css of date picker column with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem: I am using jQuery datepicker and I want to color all cell for Sunday and Saturday in red but I am not able to do so..

Here is what I have done :

```
<script>
var te=jQuery('div[id$=datepicker]');
$(function() {
  te.datepicker({ autoSize: true,prevText: "Previous   ",nextText: "  Next" });
  te.datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function() { callfromdate(); } );
  var temper=jQuery('#calRow1 tr');
  temper.css('something');
  });
</script>
```